# How to make changes in Ribbon elements of a single excel instance, using application-level add-in?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto, state, ribbon

I'm using VSTO with VB.NET for Excel 2013. I'm developing an application-level add-in, but I can't make two different workbooks store different "ribbon state". For example, when I want to enable a button, I use the following code:

```
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.myButton.Enable = False
```

This makes the element "myButton" to be disabled on each opened workbook, but I want to make it disabled only for one workbook.

The way I'm doing now is to handle the event WorkbookActivate, to change the ribbon state. The problem is: this way, the user sees an invalid state at other workbooks that are not on the top.

There is some better workaround? There isn't a way to manage the ribbon instances (and not only the global element as I am doing)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> There is some better workaround? There isn't a way to manage the ribbon instances (and not only the global element as I am doing)?

You need to use callbacks instead. Try to use the getEnabled callback instead.

Moreover, when required you can use the [IRibbonUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864687.aspx) interface methods to force Office applications to update the UI controls. The [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate(v=office.14).aspx) method invalidates the cached values for all of the controls of the Ribbon user interface. See [Overview of the IRibbonUI Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) .

You can read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx)